# Sectional curvature of 3-hyperbolic space

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, curvature

For a pair of $(X,Y)$ of linearly independent vectors in $T_pM$, $p\in M$, the sectional curvature is defined as

$$K_p(X,Y)= - \frac{\bigl\langle R(X,Y)X,Y\bigr\rangle}{|X|^2 |Y|^2 - \langle X,Y\rangle^2}$$

The problem I'm looking at now asks us to compute the sectional curvature on $\mathbb{H}^3 = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3| z>0\}$ with the metric $g= 1/z^2(dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2)$ (and hence show that it is the constant $-1$).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are asking the question in the physics stack exchange, I assume you can do the computation but what stops you is the language in which the problem is phrased. I shall offer a translation in the following:

When people write $R(X,Y)Z$, people think the Riemann tensor as a multilinear map that takes three sections of the tangent bundle as inputs and output another section. It should be translated to physicists' notation by $R(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i},\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j})\frac{\partial}{\partial x^l}=R_{ijl}^{k}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}$ where $R_{ijl}^{k}$ is the Riemann tensor you are familiar with.

Now for $K(X,Y)$, you just need to translate it to $K_{ij}=K(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i},\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j})$ for various $i,j$, and then compute the right hand side.